# Inventory script

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

Noob here, I need to extract some data from a cim interrogation of a list of servers, however the csv output is just the same reiteration of the local server, with the sum total equaling the number of lines in the input file. I think I'm doing something wrong  with the array but Ive been beating my head.  Help?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
 
#Define Some Variables
$importpath = "c:\directory1"
$workingpath = "c:\directory2"

#Do Some Filtering
Import-CSV -Path "$importpath\somefile.csv" | where {$_.Powerstate -ne "PoweredOff"} | where Guest -notlike *somestring* | Export-Csv "$workingPath\PRODUCTION.csv" -NoTypeInformation  

Import-csv -Path "$workingPath\PRODUCTION.csv" | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv -Path "$workingpath\SERVERS.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Create final input foreach routine
Import-CSV -Path "$workingpath\SERVERS.csv" | Out-file $workingpath\SERVERS.txt

$servers = Get-Content -path "$workingpath\SERVERS.txt"

$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
                Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object *

                }

$results | Export-Csv -Path "$workingPath\PRODUCTIONRESULTS.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the computername when you run the Get-CimInstance command

```
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object *

                }
```